# How to resolve "application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions"

Tags: angular, ionic3, ionic4, angular8

Hi I'm trying to get the lat and long values in ionic-4. My issue here is, when I try to get the lat and long values initially it is throwing error **application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions**. However, after user allow the access to location, When I refresh the screen, then I can get the lat and long values. Below is my code which I tried.

Followed this documentation: [ionic geolocaiton document](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation)

- I'm using `@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx`
- I created `service` with name `location.service.ts`. below is the code

```js
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx;
constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) {
   
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({maximumAge: 1000, timeout: 5000,
      enableHighAccuracy: true }).then((resp) => {
      console.log("geo location values", resp);
      
      this.servcurlat = resp.coords.latitude
      this.servcurlong = resp.coords.longitude
      console.log("lactionservice latlongs",this.servcurlat, this.servcurlong);

      let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
    watch.subscribe((data) => {
      this.goeData = data;
      this.movelatlong = this.goeData.coords;
      this.movelat = this.goeData.coords.latitude;
      this.movelong = this.goeData.coords.longitude;
      console.log("moving data" , this.goeData);      
    });

    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);    
    });
  }
}
```

- And calling `location service` in constructor of `app.component.ts` component. Below is the code

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { LocationService } from './_services/location.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  curlat: any = '';
  curlong: any = '';

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private localnotifications: LocalNotifications,
    private complaintservice: ComplaintregService,
    private locationservice: LocationService,
  ) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.initializeApp(statusBar, splashScreen);
    });
  }

  initializeApp(statusBar: StatusBar,
    splashScreen: SplashScreen) {

      this.curlat = this.locationservice.servcurlat;
      this.curlong = this.locationservice.servcurlong
      console.log("lat and long values: ",this.curlat,this.curlong);
  }
}
```

The issue here is, location service is firing before user allowing the location. when I refresh the screen, now user already allowed the location. So I can get the values.

Please let me know possible way get out of this issue. Thanks in advance and solution will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to get permission after splashscreen page, for example in your login page .